# Closure compiler issues with object

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to compile my Js code in [google closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and I am getting error on this code

```
  var settings = {
                 providers: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                 interface: 'basic16',
                 apikey: 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
                 }
```

Errors are

```
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. invalid property id at line 3 character 10
interface: 'basic16',
          ^
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. syntax error at line 3 character 11
interface: 'basic16',
           ^
JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. syntax error at line 4 character 8
apikey: 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
        ^
```

But this code works perfect for me in any browser (chrome, firefox, opera, safari, IE7,8,9)

Comment: "interface" seems to be a keyword reserved for future use, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words - enclose the identifier in quotation marks and you should be fine.

Comment: @Niko - You are correct, so you should post that as an answer!

Comment: Are you sure it works in IE8? According to the [Kangax compat table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) reserved words as property names should throw an error in IE8.

Comment: @James Allardice : yeah it was working perfect in IE8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MDN states that the keyword `interface` is reserved for future use and may not be used for property/function/variable names.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Thing is, that the MDN also states that the usage of this keyword is only restricted when in strict mode. So I'm not quite sure whether the closure compiler is doing the right thing when it complains about this even in non-strict mode. This looks more like a bug, but it's probably better to avoid using these keywords anyway.

However, a solution is to simply wrap the identifier in quotation marks:

```
var settings = {
    providers: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'interface': 'basic16',
    apikey: 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Ecmascript 3 disallowed keywords and reserved keywords as property names. Ecmascript 5 lifted this restriction (they are still disallowed as variable and function names).  However, the compiler uses ecmascript 3 mode by default.

Comment: Along these lines, adding the `--language_in ECMASCRIPT5` command line option worked for me.

Comment: If you use the latest release, these should no longer be error but warnings.  In ES3 mode the compiler will rewrite keyword property references to be quoted access:  foo.interface becomes foo['interface'].